# failed to delete a cloud sql instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I failed to delete a cloud sql instance.

```
gcloud sql instances delete $SQL_INSTANCE --quiet  --project=$GCP_PROJECT
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.delete) HTTPError 409: Operation failed because another operation was already in progress.
```

Even I waited for 1 night for the operation to timeout, the problem still happened

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Google Cloud Platform support.

This issue can happen because of synchronization of operations between your instance and the Cloud SQL service.

The operation in progress has been cancelled. You should be able now to delete the instance without any obstacle.

If the error happens again, and if you have technical support, please go to [technical support](https://support.google.com/cloud). If you do not have technical support, please go to [billing support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing/).